# Mixed content (http, https) fix

Tags: html, https, http, static

I am a digital marketing with enough HTML/CSS skill to be dangerous, correct problems, but also cause them.  So I tend to stick to WordPress.

I inherited an entirely static HTML site that I'm trying to optimize.  The easy things (some content, tags, etc) are easy.

But I have installed SSL and forced HTTPS via .htaccess.  There is some mixed content in the code, so even though it's serving on HTTPS, still getting the 'not secure' warning in browsers.

If the website is basically just static HTML, can I just do search/replace in the code and find the HTTP assets and change them to https?

I actually just went through this exercise with a Wordpress site, and obviously there's a search an replace that digs in within 20 seconds and does it all for you...so I guess I'm wondering if I can do this with just a text editor and the HTML code.

Comment: Try something like jedit. Search and Replace is fairly easy.

Comment: If I can use jedit, can I just use something like notepad and do the search and replace?

Comment: I think bulk replace is fairly easy in jedit. I remember using it once for multiple files. Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/84007/find-and-replace-text-within-multiple-files

Comment: Cool I'll check it out...thanks !